# php insert text into a href

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I'm working on using htmlpurifier to create a text-only version of my site.
I now need to replace all the a hrefs with the text only url i.e. 'www.example.com/aboutus' becomes 'www.example.com/text/aboutus'

Initially I tried a simple str_replace on the domain (I use a global variable for the domain), but the problem is links to files also get replaced i.e.
'www.example.com/document.pdf' becomes 'www.example.com/text/document.pdf' and therefore fails.

Is there a regular expression where I can say replace domain with domain/text where the url does not include string?

Thanks for any pointers you might be able to give me :)

Comment: This would probably be easier to do with Javascript, considering Javascript has DOM selectors that don't involve checking the entire page via regex.

Comment: @MoarCodePlz: So does PHP! What are you talking about?

Comment: A single line via jquery ($('a').each(function() { if ($(this).attr('href') == SOMEQUALITY) $(this).attr('href', newValue); }); would be a lot simpler than any php implementation that I know of. I could be missing something though.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'd like to stick with PHP if possible as with it being a text-only version, all styles and js are stripped out.  Also to get everything working dynamically, the generated html is placed into a PHP variable anyway, so I guess I just need to do a regex on the string... but that is where my skills run out lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$output = preg_replace(
             '#www.example.com(?!/text/)#', 
             'www.example.com/text', 
             $input
          );
```

Better yet, use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) with it:

```
$html = '<a href="www.example.com/something">foo</a>
         <p>hello</p>
         <a href="www.example.com/text/documents">bar</a>';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // supresses DOM errors

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$hrefs = $xpath->query('//a/@href');
foreach ($hrefs as $href) {
    $href->value = preg_replace(
                      '#^www.example.com(?!/text/)(.*?)(?<!\.pdf)$#', 
                      'www.example.com/text\\1', 
                      $href->value
                   );
}
```

This should give you:

```
<a href="www.example.com/text/something">foo</a>
<p>hello</p>
<a href="www.example.com/text/documents">bar</a>
```

Comment: Thanks netcoder - Just off to a meeting, but that sounds interesting! I'll report back shortly.

Comment: I'm back! I've had problems using DOM because I have name and id used on some elements so I get the 'ID already defined in Entity' error.  I've struggling to get the php negative lookaround example working too.  If I run it with $input = "http://www.example.com/aboutus<br />http://www.example.com/testing123<br />http://www.example.com/info/test<br />http://www.example.com/document.pdf";, I only get 'aboutus' becoming 'text/aboutus'.  All the others remain as before.

Comment: @user287212: For DOM, use `libxml_use_internal_errors` to suppress errors. I fixed the pattern (added a trailing `/` in both examples and removed the `^` at the beginning of the first example). See updated answer.

Comment: Hi netcoder. I'll check it out in the morning when I'm back in the office, but thank you very much for your help today :)

Comment: Hi netcoder.  Sorry for the delay in getting back to you.  I've given it a go, but the link to the PDF also gets rewritten to include '/text'.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user287212: No, I forgot that part of the question... ;) Updated the answer. You'll have to use DOM for that though, as it's pretty hard to figure out when the URL finishes without it.

Comment: Thanks netcoder - that DOM version is working perfectly :)  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Just one more thing lol... how can I add in other words to exclude?  For example, I need to exclude any link that contains the word 'download'.  Sorry to be a pest.